# TensorFlow model saving to be approached differently during training Vs. deployment?

Tags: tensorflow

Assume that I have a CNN which I am training on some dataset. The most important part of the model is the CNN architecture.

Now when I write a code, I define the model structure in a Python class. However, outside that class, I define a number of other nodes such as loss, accuracy, tf.Variable to keep count of epochs and so on.

When I am training, for properly resuming the training, I'd like to save all these nodes (e.g - loss, epoch variable etc), and not just the CNN structure.

However, once I am done with training, I would like to save only the CNN architecture and no nodes for loss, accuracy etc. This is because it will enable people using my model to exercise freedom in writing their own finetuning codes.

1. How to achieve this in TF code ? Can someone show an example ?
2. Is this approach towards saving followed by others also ?  I just want to know if my approach is right.